# Getting the index of successive minimum comparisons

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Say if i have a tensor

```
values = torch.tensor([5., 4., 8., 3.])
```

and i want to take the minimum over every 2 successive values, meaning

```
min(5., 4.) = 4.
min(8., 3.) = 3.
```

is there a vectorized way of doing it and still obtaining back the relative index of the minimum? Meaning what I want as output is:

```
min_index = [1, 1]
#min_index[0] == 1 as 4. is the minimum of (5., 4.) and is in index 1 of (5., 4.)
#min_index[1] == 1 as 3. is the minimum of (8., 3.) and is in index 1 of (8., 3.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think reshaping your tensor will make it a lot easier.
After that the `torch.min` automatically returns the minimum values and indexes.

```
import torch

values = torch.tensor([5., 4., 8., 3.])
values_reshaped = values.reshape(-1,2) # works for any length
minimums, index = torch.min(values_reshaped, axis = -1)
print(minimums) # tensor of the minimum values
print(index) # tensor of indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a numpy implementation:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,100, 10)
a
array([24, 60, 33, 65,  7, 84, 44, 67, 96, 18])

# Compare pairwise and get all pairs min relative index
min_index = np.argmin([a[:-1], a[1:]], axis=0)
min_index
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64)

# Pairs (24,60), (60,33), (33,65), and so on..

# Adding index and array location we get the global index of pairs min in the original array
global_min_index = [i+e for i,e in enumerate(min_index_tmp)]
global_min_index 
[0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 9]
```